# VS2015 Compiler Complaints that an Optional Parameter is missing

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, optional-parameters

I have a project that will not compile. The compile error is:

> Error BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'referenceTime' of
>   'Public Shared Function IsTimeBetween(startTime As TimeSpan, endTime
>   As TimeSpan, [referenceTime As TimeSpan = Nothing]) As Boolean'

Screenshot of the error:
[image]

*However* the parameter that is missing is **optional**. This is the method declaration:

```
Public Shared Function IsTimeBetween(
              ByVal startTime As TimeSpan, 
              ByVal endTime As TimeSpan, 
              Optional ByVal referenceTime As TimeSpan = Nothing) As Boolean
```

When I add a comma to the call, intellisense shows the parameter in square brackets indicating that it is optional, but won't compile without it:

Is this a bug? or am I missing something here? This project has compiled before so I am stumped what could be wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Surely yet another Roslyn bug, hard to repro.  Using Nothing as a default on a structure type is a bit icky and surely doesn't get put to the test very often.  Making it nullable might be a workaround.  Or waiting for VS2015 Update 1, currently in RC.  Or [reporting the bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/new).

Comment: Agreed that `Nothing` is not the best option for a value type. This class is exposed via COM interop so nullable types won't work here.

Comment: COM interop is not an unsubtle detail.  There is a known Roslyn problem with optional arguments in type libraries.  A good way to pull that trigger is to target a .NET framework version less than 4.0

Comment: Ok thanks @HansPassant will do some investigation into that